# Angular npm install works but npm ci gives errors

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, npm

i've got an issue where I have an ASP.NET core app that hosts an Angular application.

running `npm install` works fine, however `npm ci` does not work and gives the following errors:

Error:

```
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
npm WARN lockfile Optional missing: fsevents@2.2.1
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'requires' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     XX\_logs\2020-04-30T13_32_04_555Z-debug.log
```

Debug logfile:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'ci'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.15.0
4 verbose npm-session 92a2c0a95ca42a4b
5 info prepare initializing installer
6 verbose prepare starting workers
7 verbose prepare installation prefix: XX\ClientApps
8 verbose prepare using package-lock.json
9 warn prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
10 verbose checkLock verifying package-lock data
11 warn lockfile Optional missing: fsevents@2.2.1
12 verbose teardown shutting down workers.
13 info teardown Done in 0.001s
14 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'requires' of undefined
14 verbose stack     at addChild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-logical-tree\index.js:128:24)
14 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-logical-tree\index.js:113:5
14 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
14 verbose stack     at lockTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-logical-tree\index.js:107:5)
14 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libcipm\index.js:144:21
15 verbose cwd C:\Repos\HMI4-2\Plugins\CommonPlugins\WebHmiPlugins\WebHmi.App\ClientApps
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ci"
18 verbose node v12.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error Cannot read property 'requires' of undefined
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm clueless about what to do about this, and why install works but ci doesn't. Could anybody help me figure out why npm ci crashes and how i could resolve this error?

EDIT:
fsevents is defined as an optional dependency:

```
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "fsevents": "2.2.1",
        "node-sass": "4.12.0",
        "protractor": "5.4.2",
        "ts-node": "8.4.1",
        "tslint": "5.20.0"
    }
```

So i thought the `-no-optional` flag would help. I nuked node_modules and package-lock.json ran `npm install -no-optional` and then `npm ci -no-optional`. Aside from a bunch of warnings (see below) when running the install, i had the same error as above.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'XX\ClientApps\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'XX\ClientApps\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.abbrev.DELETE'
```

EDIT2:

Added the following logging/output:

`C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-logical-tree\index.js`

```js
function addChild (dep, tree, allDeps, pkgLock) {
  console.log("==============")
  tree.addDep(dep)
  console.log(dep)
  allDeps.set(dep.address, dep)
  const addr = dep.address
  console.log(addr)
  const lockNode = atAddr(pkgLock, addr)
  console.log(lockNode)
  Object.keys(lockNode.requires || {}).forEach(name => {
    const tdepAddr = reqAddr(pkgLock, name, addr)
    let tdep = allDeps.get(tdepAddr)
    if (!tdep) {
      tdep = makeNode(name, tdepAddr, atAddr(pkgLock, tdepAddr))
      addChild(tdep, dep, allDeps, pkgLock)
    } else {
      dep.addDep(tdep)
    }
  })
}
```

Result:

```
==============
LogicalTree {
  name: 'fsevents',
  version: undefined,
  address: 'fsevents',
  optional: false,
  dev: false,
  bundled: false,
  resolved: undefined,
  integrity: undefined,
  dependencies: Map {},
  requiredBy: Set {
    LogicalTree {
      name: 'XXMYAppName',
      version: '0.0.0',
      address: '',
      optional: false,
      dev: false,
      bundled: false,
      resolved: undefined,
      integrity: undefined,
      dependencies: [Map],
      requiredBy: Set {}
    }
  }
}
fsevents
undefined
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'requires' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-05T08_35_18_624Z-debug.log
```

EDIT3:

Packages.json

```
{
    "name": "XX",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "echo Starting... && ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "build-libs": "ng build core-lib && ng build dialog-lib && ng build services-lib && ng build components-lib",
        "build-app-dashboard": "ng build dashboard-app --base-href /dashboard/ --prod",
        "build-app-infeed": "ng build infeed-app --base-href /infeed/ --prod",
        "build-apps": "npm run build-app-dashboard && npm run build-app-infeed",
        "build-all": "npm run build-libs && npm run build-apps",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "//": [
        "Please use fixed versions instead of prefixing it with ~ or ^ or using 'latest'.",
        "Run command `npm outdated` to check whether newer versions are available."
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/cdk": "9.2.2",
        "@angular/common": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/core": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.29",
        "@angular/forms": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/material": "8.2.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/platform-server": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/router": "9.1.4",
        "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.4",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
        "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "1.2.1",
        "@progress/kendo-angular-gauges": "3.0.0",
        "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "2.0.0",
        "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "2.0.1",
        "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.6.0",
        "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "4.12.0",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "3.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
        "core-js": "3.3.3",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "ngx-moment": "3.5.0",
        "oidc-client": "1.9.1",
        "popper.js": "1.16.0",
        "rxjs": "6.5.3",
        "tslib": "1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "0.10.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.4",
        "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "0.901.4",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/cli": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.4",
        "@angular/language-service": "9.1.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "3.4.4",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
        "@types/node": "12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "5.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
        "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
        "nl2br-pipe": "1.2.3",
        "typescript": "3.8.3"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "fsevents": "2.2.1",
        "node-sass": "4.12.0",
        "protractor": "5.4.2",
        "ts-node": "8.4.1",
        "tslint": "5.20.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your missing a package dependency

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID looks so indeed, however npm install works and the app runs fine after that, so i'd expect both to crash in that case.

Comment: it's couldn't be a silly mistake using `requires` instead of `require` could it ?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(addr)` to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-logical-tree\index.js` at line 128 (before `Object.keys`) and run `npm ci` again? Just to check what's it's looking for

Comment: @David great suggestion! i've added the results to the answer, if you could check em out.

Comment: Does your package-lock.json contain fsevents?

Comment: Can you show your package.json dependencies ?

Comment: @DipakTelangre added it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with version of "fsevents" you have specified. Version "2.2.1" doesn't exists. Latest version of fsevents available in npmjs is "2.1.3".

npm install doesn't fails because you have specified fsevents in optionalDependencies. And npm install succeeds even if any optionalDependency fails.

But npm ci exits with an error if dependencies in package-lock.json do not match with those in package.json. So, instead of updating package-lock.json it will exit with an error.

One more thing, you are using --no-optional incorrectly. Notice the additional hypen(-) in  --no-optional. Try adding version 2.1.3 for fsevents or try running npm ci --no-optional.

Comment: it would not seem logical to mee that npm would compare the lockfile and the normal package.json - i'd think npm ci would only look at the package-lock file. You're right 2.1.3 is the latest version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents The problem is - i don't even want to include this package at all - but it seems baked in to angular. i don't think i can just remove it or something..

Comment: No, its written in npm ci documentation that if dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, npm ci will exit with an error. Check this out https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html

Comment: you're right! unfortunately --no-optional won't build still  and again fsevents is not my own dependency its a dependency of the angular framework so i can't remove it so this answer wont help me much im afraid :(

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the **fsevents** version in package-lock.json mismatches with in package.json

npm ci verifies from the package-lock.json. If the versions mismatch it will exit with an error. But npm install will only look into the package.json and start adding them to node_modules. if the version is not mentioned in package-lock.json it will be automatically added by npm install

Comment: Welp, NPM install works - so running npm ci after that should work which it doesnt.

Comment: npm install will not write to  package-lock.json  if the dependency is already there. It will only write the missing dependencies.

Comment: hm i see. I have however also remove the package.lock completely and then tried to recreate the package-lock file with npm install however that didn't help either

Comment: Remove the node_modules folder. Then make sure both package-lock.json and package.json files are having the correct versions (versions should be exact) and run npm ci command (do not run npm install now). npm ci installs a n entire project. not a single dependency.

Comment: in package.json fsevents is an optional dependency with version 2.2.1. in package-lock.json this is used 4 times, for versions ^1.2.7 and once for ~2.1.2 - running ci as you described above gave the same error.

Comment: angular indirectly depends on fsevent 1.2.12 which is not suppose to compile in windows. it requires a darwin-OS. but npm ci will not omit the optional dependencies while installing like npm install does. Because its used in Continuous Integrations. Anyhow per my finding related to this issue, this is a bug which will be fixed in fsevent 2.x. Therefore, you can use npm install until this is fixed. However, in most of the cases using npm ci wont be an issue since it exit with 0. Until the issue is fixed with you can use npm install. 
npm ci --no-optional didnt work for me

Comment: `npm ci --no-optional` did not work indeed, which i added to the answer. i'd like to use npm ci however since it is faster and i'd like to build angular in ci as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
npm WARN lockfile Optional missing: fsevents@fsevents
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'requires' of undefined
```

Simply resolved removing `fsevents` from `optionalDependencies`

Answer (score -1):

Try below as it works for me:

> 1. Delete the existing node_modules in the project
> 2. Update your npm
> 3. `install @angular/cli`

Now try with `npm ci`

Answer (score -2):

Delete the node modules. 
Then use the code
npm install

after that 
npm install @angular/cli

And then check if ng serve is working or not.